# How to give a default value to a textfield when using bloc framework

Tags: dart, flutter, bloc

I've written some simple flutter apps which use stateful widgets / forms / textformfields to enter and manage data. Now I'm trying to understand how to use BLoCs and streambuilders to do similar work. But I can't work out how to set initial values for my fields.

I've tried to create the simplest example I could come up with of a tiny app using a bloc. This just takes a name that is entered into a TextField and echos it onto the next line.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Bloc Example',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage();

  String initialData = 'Fred';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Bloc Example')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
          StreamBuilder(
            initialData: initialData,
            stream: bloc.nameStream,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if ( snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
                  _controller.text = snapshot.data;
                return TextField(
                  controller: _controller,
                  onChanged: bloc.nameChangedStream,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Enter name' ),
                );
              }
            ),
            StreamBuilder(
              initialData: initialData,
              stream: bloc.nameStream, //
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return Text('Name is ${snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data : 'unknown'}');
              }
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Bloc
{
  final nameStreamController = BehaviorSubject<String>();
  Stream<String> get nameStream => nameStreamController.stream;
  Function(String) get nameChangedStream => nameStreamController.sink.add ;
}

final Bloc bloc = new Bloc();
```

I can't work out how to specify an initial value to my name field.

I must admit, coming from an old style programming background, it's taking me a while to get my mind into reactive programming - but onwards and upwards!

EDIT - thanks to the comments given - updated the code to use a combination of TextEditingController and StreamBuilder initialData and seems to be working ok. Happy to take further comments if there's a better solution :)

Comment: can you provide the solution you used?

Answer (score 10):

You can give your behaviorSubject a seed value that will be used as its initial value by doing this.

```
final nameStreamController = BehaviorSubject<String>.seeded('InitialName');
```

for older versions of rxDart, use

```
final nameStreamController = BehaviorSubject<String>(seedValue:'InitialName');
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. If I add the seeded value in my example code I can see the InitialName in my Text widget. But I'm still trying to get the TextField to have InitialName as it's initial value.  I guess I could use a TextFormField and set initialValue, or use a TextEditingController - but neither of these seem particularly elegant.

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing what you want to do with the name field, there are a few routes you can go.

You could supply a `hintText` to the `InputDecoration` (`InputDecoration(hintText: 'name')`).

You could set an initial value on the StreamBuilder:

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: bloc.nameStream,
  initialData: 'Initial Name',
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      return TextField(
        onChanged: bloc.nameChangedStream,
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Enter name' ),
      );
    }
  ),
```

Though, that won't persist that value in the stream, so if the user doesn't change the text field, 'Initial Name' won't be in your `nameStreamController`'s stream.

As @nonybrighto mentioned, you can seed your `nameStreamController` with the initial value.

If you cannot use a seeded value, you could also add an initial value to your stream during the bloc's init:

```
class Bloc {
  final nameStreamController = BehaviorSubject<String>();
  Stream<String> get nameStream => nameStreamController.stream;
  Function(String) get nameChangedStream => nameStreamController.sink.add;

  Bloc() {
    String initialValue = _getInitialValue();
    nameStreamController.add(initialValue);
  }
}
```

Here's a more full, real-world example: we found this authentication and login BLoC example in which we followed a lot of the stuff laid out here: [Didier Boelens BloC Example](https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/12/reactive-programming---streams---bloc---practical-use-cases/#4-form-validation). It shows you how can use BLoC, reactive programming, and streams to set up a registration form and auth.

Comment: We totally forgot about seeding your stream controller as nonybrighto brought up. I'd go that route instead of adding the value during init, as seen in our last example.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to do that by the using of RxDart, flutter 3.0

firstly,

1. Get initial text from cache state.(Store inside shared pref or some where).
2. Declare `TextEditingController` to store that text.
3. Call that method, which return initial text from `initState` method.

For `StreamBuilder`

1. Wrap your `TextField` with StreamBuilder.
2. Inside of StreamBuilder for the `stream`, use the stream you want to listen.
3. Inside of `builder` method of `StreamBuilder` check both the condition of `snapShot` and textEditingController with conditional statement and swap each other.

Here is my example code. I used `SharedPreference` to store data.

This code is retrieve from storage.

```
  final TextEditingController _cacheUserIdCtrl = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    getCacheUserId();
    super.initState();
  }

  void getCacheUserId() {
    SharedPref.retriveData(key: SharedPref.userId).then(
      (value) {
        _cacheUserIdCtrl.text = value!;
      },
    );
  }
```

This part is the setting of text field with `Streambuilder` and set initial text. And you can edit either.

```
Widget userIdField({required LoginBloc loginBloc}) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: loginBloc.userIdStream,
      builder: (context, snapShot) {
        if (snapShot.hasData) {
          _cacheUserIdCtrl.text = snapShot.data!;
        } else {
          loginBloc.fillUserId(_cacheUserIdCtrl.text);
        }
        return TextFormField(
          onChanged: (value){
            TextSelection previousSelection = _cacheUserIdCtrl.selection;
            _cacheUserIdCtrl.selection = previousSelection;
            loginBloc.fillUserId;
          },
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          controller: _cacheUserIdCtrl,
          maxLength: 8,
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
          onSaved: (value) {
            userId = value!;
          },
          decoration: textFieldInputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Enter user id',
          ).copyWith(
            prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person),
            counterText: "",
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

For the bloc part, I assume you will do yourself.
That is for all. Will work.